# Call a 'Fathers' function form a 'Children' component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have the next component 'Father' that contains a 'Children' component in React js.

```
var Father = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Children/>
            </div>
        );
    },
    onUpdate: function(state) {
        this.setState(state);
    } });
```

I want to call the onUpdate function on the father from the children BUT without calling the 'Children' method 'componentDidUpdate' because I'm using that method for some other thing that breaks my application.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it down in properties. If you need to update only specific parts and prevent your children from updating, use the method [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate)

```
var Father = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <Children onUpdateCallback={this.onUpdate}/>
        </div>
    );
  },
  onUpdate: function(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function () { ... },

  shouldComponentUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) { ... return false}
});
```

If your Children can't/shouldn't update while the Parent does, I think you are probably doing something wrong, but good luck.

Comment: That looks good, but i have two questions: 1. When do I call the fathers onUpdate Function and what do I have to do inside the shouldComponentUpdate function?